# source activate virtualenv does nothing

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

I installed python through `brew install python`,then i installed virtualenv by `pip install virtualenv`.
then i add 'export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin' to .zshrc.
And i created a virtual enviroment by `virtualenv ENV` and no errors.
But finally i executed `source ENV/bin/activate` it did nothing.
(sorry,i can not post images,no requtations,I said nothing is nothing,all is like i never typed something)It looks like this:

```
py2 virtualenv ENV
New python executable in ENV/bin/python
Installing setuptools,pip...done
py2 source ./ENV/bin/activate
py2
py2 (nothing prompt)
```

so what's wrong with it?
thanks a lot.

PS,sorry for my poor english.

Comment: What are you expecting it to have done?

Comment: did your prompt change to have `(ENV)` in front of it?

Comment: From parent dir where you did `virtualenv ENV` try `cd ENV`, then `source bin/activate`, do you get the `(ENV)` prompt then?

Comment: no,i had tried it just now,nothing changed.

Comment: What does `which python` show?

Comment: What's `py2`? Is it a prompt or a command invoking the Python interpreter?